# React Native Pressable invoke system sound on press

Tags: android, react-native

I am using [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) (RN 0.70) to have a custom area being pressable with ripple effect etc. but I can't find a way to make the "system sound" get fired on press.

The `android_disableSound` property is set to `false` but there is no sound played on press. When closing the app and interacting with the settings etc. the system sounds are played.

Anyone knows why this is so?

Edit: I manually fired the touch sound but same result :-(

```js
import SoundManager  from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/Sound/SoundManager'

const onPress = () => SoundManager.playTouchSound()

// ... pressable
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother, I was facing the same issues, Now I am using the [TouchableOpacity](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity) it works properly with the proper tap sound.

So I recommend you use TouchableOpacity instead of Pressable.